# How to get all messages of outgoing mail in Django

Tags: python, django

I am finding a way to grab emails and attachments by email address.
With Incoming mail, i am getting all messages of Inbox mail through IMAP or POP3 via django-mailbox backage. 
But How to get all messages of Outgoing mail (SMTP).

Comment: Are your emails going through a django app ? Your django is a SMTP relay ?

Comment: post some code and some more info about the problem

Comment: @NabIlovich: No. I dont use Django app to send email. I just want to get messages in "Sent box" of this mail account.

Comment: @ArpitSolanki: I followed this tutorial here: https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/django-mailbox/latest/django-mailbox.pdf. 
install django-mailbox package then run command "python manage.py getmail" to get all incoming messages in mail account. It DONE. But this package can not get all outgoing messages. Could you tell me how can i do that? Special thanks.

Comment: So you want to build a mail client with django ? Outgoing emails are stored in a specific folder like : `/Sent`. Since you're able to request `/Inbox` you should be able to get messages in `/Sent`. But please be more specific about your problem, what is the email backend ? What's the code your using to request emails trough IMAP or POP3 ?